# Custom user fields, saving multiple values from checkbox group

Tags: php, wordpress

Im currently in the making of adding different custom fields to a user in wordpress....

Adding simple text fields like a facebook, instagram field is easy enough, however when adding I want a checkbox group giving the user the possiblity to check multiple choices, im not sure on how to save it?

Lets say I have this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="running" />Running<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="soccer" />Soccer<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="swimming" />Swimming<br />
```

How would I go about when saving the values to the database? 
I've tried this when saving:

```
$userprofile_sports = (isset($_POST['sport']) && $_POST['sport'] <> '') ? $_POST['sport'] : '';
update_user_meta($userid, 'sport', $userprofile_sports);
```

Comment: this link might be helpful http://www.wastedpotential.com/html-multi-checkbox-set-the-correct-way-to-group-checkboxes/

Comment: Look like you may need to loop through sport array and get individual values

Comment: Wuhuu, thx for the links... Solved it... thx